# The number of idempotent endomorphisms of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, idempotents

Recall that a endomorphism $f:G\longrightarrow G$ of a group $G$ is called idempotent if $f\circ f=f$.

If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, then how many idempotent endomorphisms $f:G\longrightarrow G$ are there? Is there a good upper bound for the set of all  idempotent endomorphisms of $G$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's certainly an upper bound of 2^n.  This is the carnality of the set of maps between G and itself.  Further restrictions can easily be found.  I don't know about a good upper bound though.

Comment: @ Dionel Jamie Thank you. I think your mean was $n^n$.

Comment: The number of idempotent endomorphisms of a set of size $n$ is known (https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/number-of-idempotent-endofunctions/) so that's certainly a tighter upper bound. If $G$ is abelian then you can in principle exactly count the number of idempotent endomorphisms since they correspond exactly to direct sum decompositions, although it'll get messy.

Comment: It's the number of pairs of subgroups $H,K$ such that $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and $K$. Using an [essentially optimal bound on the number of subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/q/196164) gives a quasipolynomial upper bound of $n^{\tfrac 1 2 + o(1)}\log_2(n)$ where $n=|G|$. On the other hand the elementary abelian $2$-groups have $n^{\tfrac 1 4 + o(1)}\log_2(n)$ subgroups, which each give at least one direct sum composition. I suspect the elementary abelian 2-groups actually match the upper bound. Maybe someone has computed the relevant asymptotic.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan  Thank you for the link.

Comment: @ Dap I didn't understand good. Is $n^{\frac{1}{2}+O(1)}\log_2 (n)$ an upper bound for the number of idempotent endomorphisms over $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $e(G)$ of idempotent endomorphisms over $G$ is the number of pairs of subgroups $H,K$ such that $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and $K$.
A theorem of [Borovik, Pyber and Shalev](http://www.ams.org/tran/1996-348-09/S0002-9947-96-01665-0/S0002-9947-96-01665-0.pdf) (Corollary 1.6) shows that the number of subgroups of a group $G$ of order $n=\lvert G\rvert$ is bounded by $n^{(\frac{1}{4}+o(1)) \log_2(n)}$. Squaring gives an upper bound on the total number of pairs $(H,K)$ and hence on $e(G)$:

$$e(G)\leq n^{(\frac{1}{2}+o(1)) \log_2(n)}\text{ for all $G$ with $n=|G|$}.$$

This upper bound is essentially matched by elementary abelian $2$-groups, which satisfy

$$e((\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^d)\geq 2^{\tfrac 1 2 d^2} = n^{\tfrac 1 2 \log_2(n)}\text{ with $n=2^d$}.$$

Calculations for this last claim are below.

---

The number $ob(\mathbb F_q^d)$ of ordered bases of a finite vector space $\mathbb F_q^d$ is

$$ob(\mathbb F_q^d) = q^{\binom d 2}(q^d-1)(q^{d-1}-1)\cdots (q-1).$$

The number of pairs $(H,K)$ of complementary subspaces with $\dim H=d-k$ and $\dim K=k$ is therefore given by

$$\frac{ob((\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^d)}{ob((\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^{d-k})ob((\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^k)}=q^{k(d-k)}
\frac{q^d-1}{q^k-1}
\frac{q^{d-1}-1}{q^{k-1}-1}
\cdots
\frac{q^{d-k+1}-1}{q^1-1}
\geq q^{2k(d-k)}.
$$

Setting $q=2$ and $k=d/2$ we get

$$e((\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^{d})\geq 2^{d^2/2}.$$

Comment: @ Dap  Your answer is great. Thank you very much  for your clear and detailed explanations. I understand your answer now completely.

Comment: @ Dap Excuse me. What does notation $o(1)$ denote in your answer?

Comment: @M.Mohareri: it's Landau "little-o" asymptotic notation; more explicitly it means there are values $\psi(n)>0$, with $\psi(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, such that $e(G)\leq n^{(\frac{1}{2}+\psi(n)) \log_2(n)}$ for all $n$.

Comment: @ Dap  I understood. Thank you very much.